# Stream input to stream output using 'avserver'

Tags: streaming, ip-camera, avconv

I'm trying to use the [avserver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libav#List_of_project.27s_components) package to re-stream my IP camera's stream in order to be able to record this stream and access it remotelly without having to stream it twice from the camera, to avoid overloading the wireless network.

Following the link https://libav.org/avserver.html, I came up with the following command:

```
avserver -f /etc/avserver.conf & avconv -i http://user:password@192.168.1.121/videostream.asf http://localhost:80/feed1.ffm
```

This gives me the following output

```
avserver version 0.8.3-6:0.8.3-6ubuntu2, Copyright (c) 2000-2012 the Libav developers
built on Oct  1 2012 15:03:26 with gcc 4.7.2
avconv version 0.8.3-6:0.8.3-6ubuntu2, Copyright (c) 2000-2012 the Libav developers
built on Oct  1 2012 15:03:26 with gcc 4.7.2
Mon Jan 13 20:13:44 2014 AVserver started.
[asf @ 0x153cac0] max_analyze_duration reached
[asf @ 0x153cac0] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #0, asf, from 'http://admin:gafit@192.168.1.121/videostream.asf':
Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 32 kb/s
Stream #0.0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj422p, 320x240, 100 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc
Stream #0.1: Audio: adpcm_ima_wav, 8000 Hz, 1 channels, s16, 32 kb/s
Incompatible pixel format 'yuvj422p' for codec 'mpeg1video', auto-selecting format 'yuv420p'
[buffer @ 0x153ec80] w:320 h:240 pixfmt:yuvj422p
[avsink @ 0x1544820] auto-inserting filter 'auto-inserted scaler 0' between the filter 'src' and the filter 'out'
[scale @ 0x1543460] w:320 h:240 fmt:yuvj422p -> w:320 h:240 fmt:yuv420p flags:0x4
[mp2 @ 0x1544aa0] Requested sampling rate unsupported using closest supported (16000)
Mon Jan 13 20:13:50 2014 Feed '/tmp/feed1.ffm.ffm' stream number does not match registered feed
Output #0, ffm, to 'http://localhost:80/feed1.ffm':
Metadata:
encoder         : Lavf53.21.0
Stream #0.0: Video: mpeg1video, yuv420p, 320x240 [PAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 1000k tbn, 60 tbc
Stream #0.1: Audio: mp2, 16000 Hz, 1 channels, s16, 128 kb/s
Stream mapping:
Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mjpeg -> mpeg1video)
Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (adpcm_ima_wav -> mp2)
Press ctrl-c to stop encoding
Mon Jan 13 20:13:50 2014 127.0.0.1 - - [POST] "/feed1.ffm HTTP/1.1" 200 4096
```

When I try to open this stream via [VLC media player](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VLC_media_player), using

```
http://192.168.1.15/test.asf
```

I get the following additional output

```
Mon Jan 13 20:17:39 2014 192.168.1.6 - - [GET] "/test.asf HTTP/1.1" 200 115s dup=12210 drop=0
Mon Jan 13 20:17:39 2014 Codec for stream 0 does not use global headers but container format requires global headers
Mon Jan 13 20:17:39 2014 Codec for stream 1 does not use global headers but container format requires global headers
```

And I get nothing on VLC media player. I'm not quite sure what is going on or how to fix it, so any enlightning on this would be very welcome.

Comment: Add `AVOptionVideo flags +global_header`  `AVOptionAudio flags +global_header` in <Stream> </Stream> tags in avserver.conf

Answer (score 0):

please try using another format like mp3

just

sudo vim /etc/avserver.conf

comment out the section with

```
#<stream test.asf>
#</Stream>
```

uncomment the mp3 section and try using that.

```
<stream test.mp3></Stream>
```

this would work if you are working with a stream that is only audio only.

for a video

just use the uncommented section for

```
<Stream test1.mgp><Stream>
```